# Round to 2 decimal places with JS

Tags: javascript, html

Alright so this is in a JS file that is called by an html page. Overall t_price changes to many different prices in USD dollars. 
T_price then gets converted into Singapore dollars. Doing this makes numbers like 499 into 510.38294. I need to round any number into just 2 decimal places. This is my code:

```
r_price=t_price*1.27;
m_price=Math.round(r_price*100/100);
document.getElementById("v_price").value="$"+m_price;
```

For what ever reasons - this is rounding to no decimal places instead of 2. So 510.38294 becomes just 510 instead of 510.38.

Am I using the wrong math.round? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.round() is doing exactly what you asked it to - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round.

What you want to use for is toFixed() like so

```
m_price = m_price.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: that's it! Except in my case it's
    m_price = r_price.toFixed(2);
thanks

Comment: Note that you are converting the number to a string, which is fine if you are simply displaying it; if you are doing subsequent arithmetic, you may want to use Tom van der Woerdt's answer, which results in a number.

Answer (score 7):

You wrote :

```
m_price=Math.round(r_price*100/100);
```

You meant :

```
m_price=Math.round(r_price*100)/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

X - the number; N - number of decimals

```
    function roundPlus(x, n) {
        if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(n)) return false;
        var m = Math.pow(10, n);
        return Math.round(x * m) / m;
    };
```